# How to find occurrences of a #define in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, ide

Call Hierarchy (*Ctrl+Alt+H*) works for *variables, fields, structs, types* and *functions*.

But how do i visualize the occurrences of a *#define* constant in Eclipse?

e.g.: `#define ObjSpc   "IEDM1CPUWTG"`

EDIT: 
User Lundin pointed out that the source-search (Ctrl+H in project-explorer) is capable of doing this. Thanks for the answer.

Nevertheless i wrote a featurerequest to the Eclipse CDT Project.

Comment: By the regular search tool across the entire project, me thinks.

Comment: yes, sure - but that is rather impractical; especially when the searched-for name shows up in comments or commented-out code. Isn't there something like call hierarchy ..?

Comment: Doing this `find . -type f -exec egrep -nH --color "#define[ ]+ObjSpc" \;` you can do it on a console.

Comment: find ...  thats how i did it in the first place, still im not happy with having to search like this. 

@mch that puts you to de definition, not the occurences.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Eclipse has one text search and one source search. The latter is supposed to be intelligent and somehow interact with the compiler/generated object file.

Comment: @Lundin you are the men again, thanks. thats what i needed! Can we promote this to an answer?

Comment: Eh, sure, let me just start my... _favourite IDE_... Eclipse...  and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Eclipse IDE, click the menu Search -> file search. (Or some such, this menu is apparently different on different implementations of Eclipse.) Type `#define`.

This should highlight all occurrences of `#define` that are part of the compiled source code, skipping comments etc.

Comment: Note: the 3 different implementations of Eclipse (cross-compilers) that I still have installed on my PC all had a completely different menu layout here. So the menu might as well be called FUBAR for all I know. Because... Eclipse.